# Unable to parse a json string Binary in spark scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Binary json array string which I need to parse in Spark scala.
This is what I am doing:

```
import com.github.wnameless.json.flattener.JsonFlattener


def extractBlob(jsonString: String,
              defaultValue: String = ""): String = {

 JsonFlattener
      .flatten(jsonString)
      .toString
}

val extractBlobAsText = udf((jS: String) => extractBlob(jS))
val df1 = 
df.withColumn("extracted",extractBlobAsText(unhex(col("hex").cast(StringType))))
df1.show(false)
```

But I am getting this error

```
com.eclipsesource.json.ParseException: Unexpected end of input at 1:1 at 
com.eclipsesource.json.JsonParser.error(JsonParser.java:490) at 
com.eclipsesource.json.JsonParser.expected(JsonParser.java:484) at 
com.eclipsesource.json.JsonParser.readValue(JsonParser.java:193) at 
com.eclipsesource.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:152) at 
com.eclipsesource.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:91) at 
com.eclipsesource.json.Json.parse(Json.java:295) at 
com.github.wnameless.json.flattener.JsonFlattener.<init>(JsonFlattener.java:144) at 
com.github.wnameless.json.flattener.JsonFlattener.flatten(JsonFlattener.java:100) at 
notebook0.Cell5$285.extractBlob(Cell5:12) at
```

Also, I do not know the JSON schema. All I know is that it is a Json array. So I also need to do `explode` later.

Comment: Is the data in the forma of JSON files?

Comment: yes. the json is encoded in binary

Comment: What  library are you using for converting JSON to text? is using `spark.read.json()` out of option?

Comment: Yes for both. I updated the question with the library I am using

Comment: create a StructType schema object in the `from_json` method. After the unhex method create a column using the `from_json()` method and pass the "unhexed" column and you will have a Column with Struct as datatype. You can then select the columns/keys from the struct then

Comment: The issue is, the JSON is schemaless. All I know is that it is a json